# Import Entity in dynamic web project

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, model-view-controller, ejb

I have a web project , EJB /JPA in different machine 
I am trying to call a method EJB in my managed bean that return Book b

```
Book b=ejb.getbook(1);
```

Should I import JPA Book entity in my JSF project ?

Answer (score 0):

Although possible (using decoupled entities and a 'mock' jpa jar on client), I suggest you to tranfer a DTO (Data Transfer Object). Usually there is some data from the entity that is not useful for the consumer of the EJB (entity version, date of creation, user, etc). And if you integrate that with other kind of adapters (like a Web service that supplies for Android apps) you will need a DTO. So, in my projects, my EJBs deliver DTOs by default.

You will save some bandwith as well, and simplify validation.